# Is it possible to read compressed files (tar.gz) with FileBeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I'm using ELK with FileBeat log shipper and I would like to know if it's possible to read compressed files (like tar.gz) using FileBeats without extracting?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question but for uncompressing single.gz files, not .tar.gz files which may contain multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. You can track progress in this github issue: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/637

Comment: @jocactus "Not yet" is maybe a terse answer and not helpful but it is an answer. It is not link only. even without the link the answer makes sense.